# How to edit a CSV file column and running a for loop to it

Tags: python, csv

Hi I have a CSV file with this 1,200 rows and 3 columns

```
Pat_ID | System_Disc | Syndrom_Disk
U-P-009  Respiratory    Pneumonia
U-P-010  Skin           Abscess
```

I want to run a for loop in the Pat_Id column to remove the dashes (-) so pat_id becomes UP009 instead of U-P-009. How do I do it?

Comment: have you tried any code so far? Have you looked at the python csv library? https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

Comment: use an editor and search replace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Use pandas

- Use [`pandas.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) to create a dataframe. Use the `sep` parameter if you have a separator other than `,`

  - The data is now also in an excellent format for further analysis and visualization
- Use [`.str.replace('-', '')`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html)
- Save back to a csv with [`pandas.DataFrame.to_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)

```py
import pandas as pd

# create the dataframe
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')

# display(df)
    Pat_ID  System_Disc Syndrom_Disk
0  U-P-009  Respiratory    Pneumonia
1  U-P-010         Skin      Abscess

# clean the Pat_ID column
df.Pat_ID = df.Pat_ID.str.replace('-', '')

# display(df) after fixing column
  Pat_ID  System_Disc Syndrom_Disk
0  UP009  Respiratory    Pneumonia
1  UP010         Skin      Abscess
```

### Use CSV

```py
import csv

with open('test.csv', 'r+', newline='') as f:  # open file
    lines = list(csv.reader(f, delimiter='|'))  # reads file in as a list of lists
    for i, line in enumerate(lines):
        if i > 0:  # skips the header
            lines[i][0] = line[0].replace('-', '')  # replaces the -
    f.seek(0)  # locates the beginning of the file
    f.truncate()  # removes previous contents
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(lines)  # write back to csv file


# resulting file
Pat_ID,System_Disc,Syndrom_Disk
UP009,Respiratory,Pneumonia
UP010,Skin,Abscess
```